# bootstrap - how to replicate a Iphone "Scroll Wheel"?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I don't know that Scroll Wheel is the right name for what I want, but I'll try to explain it.

On my I phone there are text boxes I can click on. Once you click on that box, you are presented with a scrollable list of items, for example numbers 1-10.

When you choose the number 1-10, either that value is placed in the text box and the list view is closed or you can "submit" that choice.

Is it possible to replicate this scrolling list of preset values in bootstrap? Ideally I want to have a list of times to choose from (1:00-1:30, 1:30-2:00) that an end user can scroll through on their phone and make a decision.

Comment: Sounds like the way mobile browsers implement select lists, or perhaps HTML5 number/date/time inputs.

Comment: That sounds like the native UI for a [`<select>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). To use the UI, you just use that element type.

Comment: Yep, that's just a normal `<select>` element. It would work like that on mobile with or without Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

**The answer to your question**

Like others have mentioned in the comments, this is just how iOS renders `<select>` elements. Different browsers will render this differently, i.e. Android browsers come up with a slightly more conventional list, and desktop browsers will render it as a standard drop down list (albeit styled to fit with their UI, which can be frustrating).

**Other things to be aware of**

Bear in mind that if you try and override the default select elements with a plugin such as [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) you will lose the various browsers default rendering of these elements, which can be one hell of a headache. There is also currently no easy way to detect whether your browser will render a select in a special way (such as the iOS style spinner) or use a dropdown, so its not like you can use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to apply your select plugin only when you're not using iOS/Android. If you want to do that you're in the murky world of user agent sniffing. (If anyone wants to correct me on this *please* do!)

**Further reading**

As a bit of an aside make sure you check out the new [HTML5 input types](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types). These provide things like native datepickers with no need for plugins (if the browser supports it) and many other types that have varying degrees of usefulness. For example, the `type="tel"` input is a nice one, that will render a normal text box in most desktop browsers, but on most phones/tablets/devices with virtual keyboards it will bring up a dial pad style keyboard, making it much easier for the suer to type in a phone number and giving them a strong indication of what you want. Just something that is very much worth thinking about if you are making forms for mobile and desktop, as it can make the mobile experience much more fluid. Browsers that don't support these elements will continue to render as they normally do as well, which is doubly nice. You can also use the likes of Modernizr to detect whether any of these input types are available to you, and do things differently. For example we have used Modernizr to detect if there is a native datepicker available, if there is, we just leave our `<input type="datepicker/>` alone, but if there is no datapicker we load in the jQuery datepicker, therefore making sure everyone has a datepicker.

This might be all obvious stuff to some of you but since this question had been pretty much answered in the comments I thought it would be useful to include some extra information about input types and different browsers rendering. If anyone wants to expand on my answer or correct anything (I'll be the first to admit to not being a complete expert on these things) please feel free.